# Magento 2 - Mass Update Tier Pricing for products

Tags: tierprice

We have 1000 products all with their own tier pricing setup (often buy 3, buy 6).

What is the fastest way of mass updating these products?

I would assume

- go to catalog
- select products
- click massupdate
- set tier pricing
- hit save

How does mass updating tier pricing work for updating large product catalogs?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use bulk api endpoints, for better performance.
Tier price updates the endpoint is

```
{{host}}/rest/async/bulk/V1/products/tier-prices/
```

or

```
{{host}}/rest/all/async/bulk/V1/products/tier-prices/
```

or

```
{{host}}/rest/<storecode>/async/bulk/V1/products/tier-prices/
```

Here an example of the json payload

```
[{
    "prices": [
    {
      "price": 66,
      "price_type": "fixed",
      "website_id": 0,
      "sku": "juice-lemon",
      "customer_group": "Gold",
      "quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "price": 55,
      "price_type": "fixed",
      "website_id": 0,
      "sku": "juice-lemon",
      "customer_group": "Silver",
      "quantity": 1
    },
    {
      "price": 44,
      "price_type": "fixed",
      "website_id": 0,
      "sku": "juice-orange",
      "customer_group": "Black",
      "quantity": 1
    },         
  ]
}
]
```

You can find format and fields explanation at the tier-price REST official documentaion
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/modules/catalog-pricing.html#manage-tier-prices

Here is the documentation about bulk endpoints and how they work
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/bulk-endpoints.html

Answer (score 1):

we recently published a module that does exactly what you need. You can find it here https://marketplace.magento.com/customgento-module-mass-update-tier-prices-m2.html.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in bulk update option for updating tier pricing.

> Rather than entering tier prices manually for each product, it can be
> more efficient to import the pricing data.

Have a look at the documentation for importing tier price data here https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/data-import-price-tier.html

You will also find many third party import tools available that enable you to import pricing data. Furthermore it is relatively easy to create your own import scripts for modifying data like this yourself. And finally, believe it or not, MAGMI is still an option for Magento 2. http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php/Tier_price_importer